# What is the best configuration of Android Phones for development on Animation Apps

Tags: android, resolution

What is the best configuration for Android Phones (devices) when working on Animation Apps?

Whether we can develop these apps on ldpi or only on hdpi & xhdpi resolutions?

Whether do we need to look into high-end processor? Device Memory?

Our current Android App has over 800+ images, and we are also looking to compress images in order to prevent memory leakages. We are loading these 800+ images when loading app. But we are selecting some 200+ images for different animations in this app such as running, crying, walking and so forth. We are seeing this animation getting faster initially but gets slowed down for couple of seconds which is impacting the video generation time. All the images are stored on the device not on the server.

Can we clear rest of unselected images from memory? What are the best methods (or free tools) for image compressions in Android?

We are using r.drawable option and Android will create ids automatically to map to the images.

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks